# Efficient region weighted sum using numpy

Tags: python, numpy, matrix

I have an index matrix defining regions that looks something like so:

```
0 0 0 0 1 1 1
0 0 0 1 1 1 1
0 0 1 1 1 1 2
0 1 1 1 1 1 2
2 2 2 2 2 2 2
3 3 3 3 3 3 3
```

I have another matrix of the same size with weights. I want to do a weighted sum over each region efficiently. Here was my first attempt:

```
n = indices.max() + 1
xSum, ySum, dSum = np.zeros(n), np.zeros(n), np.zeros(n)

for j in range(weights.shape[1]):
    for i in range(weights.shape[0]):
        ind = indices[i, j]
        density = weights[i, j]
        xSum[ind] += density * i
        ySum[ind] += density * j
        dSum[ind] += density

x, y = xSum / dSum, ySum / dSum
```

Obviously, native loops in Python aren't very fast.
My second attempt tries to use masking:

```
x, y = [], []
row_matrix = np.fromfunction(lambda i, j: i, weights.shape)
col_matrix = np.fromfunction(lambda i, j: j, weights.shape)

for ind in range(num_regions):
    mask = (indices == ind)
    xSum = sum(weights[mask] * row_matrix[mask])
    ySum = sum(weights[mask] * col_matrix[mask])
    dSum = sum(weights[mask])

    x.append(xSum / dSum)
    y.append(ySum / dSum)
```

Question is, can I do this even faster? No loops, purely on the matrix?

For testing, you can generate random big matrices like so:

```
indices = np.random.randint(0, 100, (1000, 1000))
weights = np.random.rand(1000, 1000)
```

On this data set, the first takes 1.8s, the latter takes 0.9s.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use [`np.bincount`](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.10.0/reference/generated/numpy.bincount.html):

```
import numpy as np

indices = np.random.randint(0, 100, (1000, 1000))
weights = np.random.rand(1000, 1000)

def orig(indices, weights):
    x, y = [], []
    row_matrix = np.fromfunction(lambda i, j: i, weights.shape)
    col_matrix = np.fromfunction(lambda i, j: j, weights.shape)
    num_regions = indices.max()+1
    for ind in range(num_regions):
        mask = (indices == ind)
        xSum = sum(weights[mask] * row_matrix[mask])
        ySum = sum(weights[mask] * col_matrix[mask])
        dSum = sum(weights[mask])

        x.append(xSum / dSum)
        y.append(ySum / dSum)
    return x, y

def alt(indices, weights):
    indices = indices.ravel()
    h, w = weights.shape
    row_matrix, col_matrix = np.ogrid[:h, :w]
    dSum = np.bincount(indices, weights=weights.ravel())
    xSum = np.bincount(indices, weights=(weights*row_matrix).ravel())
    ySum = np.bincount(indices, weights=(weights*col_matrix).ravel())
    return xSum/dSum, ySum/dSum

expected_x, expected_y = orig(indices, weights)
result_x, result_y = alt(indices, weights)

# check that the result is the same
assert np.allclose(expected_x, result_x)
assert np.allclose(expected_y, result_y)
```

---

Here is a benchmark:

```
In [163]: %timeit orig(indices, weights)
1 loops, best of 3: 966 ms per loop

In [164]: %timeit alt(indices, weights)
10 loops, best of 3: 20.8 ms per loop
```

Comment: Wow, that's amazing. I knew there'd be numpy tricks to do it better. The ogrid trick is also very useful, thanks!